# retrieve the data to the same html page i am using

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

using servlet code i inserted the data to database.
    and i want to retrieve that data to the same html page.....i want the servlet code 
    in the same class for inserting and editing. i am using eclipse.....so plz help me     frnds.....i am new to java and 
    my knowledge is close to nothing

**html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>PATIENT</title>
<style type="text/css">
input, textarea,select {
  background-color : lightgray;
}
table
{
border: 2px solid gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#DDDDDD">

<script>
function myFunction()
{

    var reg_no=prompt("Please enter your Register No", "")
    }
</script>

<p align ="center"><b>PATIENT</b></p><br>
<form method="post" name ="patientForm" action="patientDemo"> 
<table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td>
<font color="maroon">Register Number</font>
</td>
<td colspan="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="15" name="regs_numb" required>
</td>
<td>

   <font color="maroon">PatientId</font>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" size="18" name="pat_Id" required>
</td>
<td>
   <font color="maroon">Patient Type</font>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
   <input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" name="pat_Type">
</td>
<tr>
<td>
   <font color="maroon">Patient Name</font>
</td>
<td colspan="4">
    <input type="text" maxlength="50" size="53" name="pat_Name">
</td>

<td>
<font color="maroon">Age</font>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" maxlength="3" size="3" name="age">
<select name="age_units">
<option value="years">Years</option>
<option value="months">Months</option>
<option value="days">Days</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
  <font color="maroon">Sex</font>
</td>
<td>
<select name="sex">
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
</td>   



<td>
  <font color="maroon">Package</font>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" maxlength="10" SIZE="18" name="package">
</td>
</table>


<br>
<table align="center" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="save" id="save"/>
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="edit" id="edit"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="delete" id="delete">
</td>
<td>
<input type="reset" value="cancel" id="cancel"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="exit" id="exit"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PatientDemo.java**

```
package patientDemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




public class PatientDemo extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException

{

response.setContentType("text/html");

PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();


    String a=request.getParameter("regs_numb");
    String b=request.getParameter("pat_Id");
    String c=request.getParameter("pat_Type");
    String d=request.getParameter("pat_Name");
    String e=request.getParameter("age");
    String f=request.getParameter("age_units");
    String g=request.getParameter("sex");
    String h=request.getParameter("package");

   try

{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

System.out.println("driver loaded");
System.out.println("Driver is loaded");
Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charms","root","root");
System.out.println("Connection created");
PreparedStatement ps= ((java.sql.Connection) con).prepareStatement("insert into patient(p_reg_no_v,p_patient_id_v,p_patient_type_v,p_patientname_v,p_age_s,p_ageunit_v,p_sex_v,p_package_v) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");


        ps.setString(1,a);
        ps.setString(2,b);
        ps.setString(3,c);
        ps.setString(4,d);
        ps.setString(5,e);
        ps.setString(6,f);
        ps.setString(7,g);
        ps.setString(8,h);
ps.execute();

out.close();
System.out.println("Inserted");

}
catch(Exception e1)

{

System.out.println(e1);

}

}
}
```

Comment: it's highly recommended to follow MVC pattern for real-time application. For your question, you can use AJAX call to back-end and display the results in same page without refresh/reload.

Comment: sir i dont know how to use framework so i asked u in the same class........

Comment: @Saideep Split your tasks and google it , you will get a lot of good stuffs.

Comment: @saideep, i didn't mention any framework. I told to follow MVC pattern.

Comment: @saideep see [MVC Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp) Read and understand and try to do.IF you find any problem then we are always ready to help

Comment: @JqueryLearner plz can u give me the related example for my question i will edit and try to execute it .........

Comment: @saideep see [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/login-form-in-jsp)

Comment: @saideep I really wants to help you but I have lots of work.I can give you a simple demo using ajax if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name all your buttons something like "action".  At the top of doPost() check which button was pressed by calling request.getParameter("action") like you did for the other fields.

Branch your logic depending on the value.  For "save" you do what you are already doing.  For "delete" you would do delete SQL instead.  If it's not set, do nothing.

After all that, have the code fall though to query the database and render the page.

(edited to add example)

In the HTML, give your buttons a name like this

```
<input type="submit" value="save" id="save" name="action"/>
```

Also make place holders for your data like this

```
<input type="text" maxlength="15" name="regs_numb" required value="${regs_numb}">
```

In java do what i described above

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action.equals("save")) {
        saveData(request);
    } else if (action.equals("delete")) {
        deleteData(request);
    }
    renderPage(request, response);
}
private void renderPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // load your html file from disk
    String html = loadHtml(filename);

    // load the last data you were just editing
    String a=request.getParameter("regs_numb") // or whatever you primary key field id
    Map<String,String> model = loadSqlData(a);

    // inject the data into your html
    for(Entry<String,String> entry : model.entrySet()) {
        html = html.replace("${" + entry.getKey() +"}", entry.getValue());
    }

    // send the page to the browser
    response.getWriter().println(html);
    response.flush();
}
```

You'll need to implement those methods for saveData, deleteData, loadHtml, and loadSqlData.

For loadSqlData have it return a HashMap where the key is all the fields you put placeholder for like ${regs_numb), and the value is from the database.

If this seems like a lot of work, it is.  That's why everyone is recommending using a framework that does 90% of this for you.